# Mapping exception says, could not instantiate id generator. Why this exception?

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-many, hibernate-mapping

While trying to achieve `one to many` mapping for class `Person` and `Address` I get the following exception :`org.hibernate.MappingException: could not instantiate id generator`.

I don't know the reason for this. What could be the reason I am getting this exception ?

```
<class name="pojo.Person" table="person">
      <id name="personID" column="p_id">
          <generator class="increment" />
      </id>
      <property name="personName" column="p_name" />
      <set name="addressSet" table="address" cascade="all"> 
          <key column="p_id" />
          <one-to-many class="pojo.Address" />
      </set>
</class>


<class name="pojo.Address" table="address">
      <id name="a_id" column="a_id">
          <generator class="foreign" />
      </id>
      <property name="personAddress" column="p_address" />
</class>
```

Sql that created table:

```
CREATE TABLE person(p_id INTEGER,p_name TEXT,PRIMARY KEY(p_id));
CREATE TABLE address(a_id INTEGER,p_address TEXT);
```

*Note: One person can have more than one address*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change generator class from `foreigner` to `increment` in a key of your Address entity. For details, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17293727/432259) where I already mentioned that.